# Changing the order of fields in Customer Address Book (2.4.3)

Tags: customer-address, magento2.4.3

I would like to change the order of fields when a customer adds an address or edits an existing one in the address book.

Eg: I would like the zip-code field to be ordered before the city field.

Previously I had already handled this by copying the contents from `magento-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml`
and pasting them into `my-theme/Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml`.

I can still use this method to completely omit certain fields from the form but I can not control the order of the fields in this way any more.

Do I need to also create a layout file since the new Magento update or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the solution in my theme wasn't working, was because a module had been introduced that is also overwriting the edit.phtml.

I changed the order accordingly in the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can also update sorting customer address field from database table. you will update table `customer_eav_attribute` field `sort_order`. update query like below for zipcode show before city.

```
UPDATE `customer_eav_attribute` SET `sort_order` = '75' WHERE `customer_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 33;
```

Comment: Thank you but I would rather not touch the db directly if I can avoid it. This seems like a good way to do it if I can't fix it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `customer_address_form.xml` file, please check if the block which is calling `edit.phtml` file is `cacheable="false"`

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="Magento_Customer::address/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
```

Comment: It is indeed set to cacheable="false". I haven't touched that file yet. Is that incorrect?